# Date Field in Firefox no working with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am having trouble with this. So, I created a from that allows you select a date range. Then from there, the form populates with records from the database based on the date range. Pretty easy.

However, the date field didn't work in firefox, so I tried switching it to jquery. and how it doesn't work. I am assuming it's something with the format. So here is my jquery code:

```
  <script>

  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

and here is the mysql statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM v88374 WHERE date >= DATE_FORMAT('" . $from . "', '%Y/%m/%d') AND date <=  DATE_FORMAT('" . $to . "', '%Y/%m/%d')";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I need it to work in all browsers ahd the reason I switched jquery  was because the basic date field wouldn't work in firefox....so if someone has a better fix for this then I am definitely open to it.

Comment: can you also post your html and php form processing code ?

Comment: also is it working on browsers other than firefox ?

Comment: Why don't you use `DATE` or `DATETIME` format in your database?

Comment: `<form method="post">
<p>Select a date range: </p><label style="color:#FFF;" for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
<label style="color:#FFF;" for="to" >to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
<input name="export" type="submit" value="Sort" />
</form>`
Then php code:
`$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be treating dates as strings in your SQL query.  Use [the appropriate data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) in your database (probably `DATE`).  You should then [parameterize your query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/634824) rather than appending the values into the string.

The formatting concern should be delegated to your PHP code.  Parse the input into a [`datetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, and pass that as a parameter.  (Use the [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) function to do the parsing.)

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Follow the links in my response, there are examples there.  If you want to provide more of your PHP code to show how you are executing this query, I can adjust it for you.